# php that runs continuously on the server side and fetch data and replace the same file again and again

Tags: php, server

I have a hosted a website in free hosting site ,I am new to web programming.Now what i want to do is a want a `php` file to run on the server side continuously 24*7 and fetch the data from spreadsheet(i have `php` file which does this job) ..In the process i want a file on the server to b replaced so that it can act as the data source to the referring clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php will always be running as long as a site has been pulled from the server, and it contains php. The connection will be closed once one closes the page.

As I understand your question you can do a couple things.
The easiest would be to just set a cron job if your web hosting supports it. 
[How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php) 
 
[managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428)

Comment: basically i am just using only the backend.I am connecting to the file present there using android.I want this file to have updated version of the spreadsheet .so i need to replace it.Hope cron tab works...Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running a script continuously on the server, it is good to use [Cron Jobs in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php).

If you're on shared hosting, add similar line in cron job list,

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/<hosting-username>/public_html/path-of-php-script
```

Here, You can run the php file with some seconds/minutes/hours/days/weeks/months/years interval.